# How to perform the same tasks in SQL SERVER IN SQL AZURE?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, azure-sql-database

I connect my `SQL AZURE` to `SQL SERVER 2008 R2`.I realized that I can't use the GUI to create my tables, edit the design of the tables, insert.. update.. remove data, etc.

Is it possible that using SQL SERVER 2008R2 I can perform the last tasks using the GUI?

Another day I saw something about data synchronization with local database and azure, but I'm not sure what was that. I mention it if that is important for what I'm looking for.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use redgate toolbelt tool kit for data sync with SQL Azure . it is very very easy to use . SQL Azure dosen't provide same GUI as sql server 208 r2 . however Amazon RDS provide that facility . you can use management console for SQL Azure to view tables and data in SQL Azure .